# Existe-t-il des verbes au gérondif différent du participe présent ?

Tags: conjugaison, participe-présent, morphologie

Dans la plupart des dictionnaires ou conjugueurs, le gérondif (*en marchant*) et le participe présent (*marchant*) sont souvent indiqués l'un après l'autre ; or, pour autant que je sache, le gérondif se forme
*par définition* avec "en" suivi du participe présent, il me paraît donc redondant de toujours spécifier les deux formes.

Existe-t-il donc des cas de verbes où la partie verbale du gérondif diffère du participe présent du verbe ?

Answer (score 2):

Non, il n'en existe pas.
C'est en effet redondant, puisque le gérondif est formé, comme tu le dis, par en suivi du participe présent.
Remarquons que l'on a alors le même problème avec le participe passé: il est déjà donné dans le conjugaison du verbe au passé composé, et est donc aussi redondant.
Je ne sais pas si c'est une explication à cette redondance, mais contrairement au gérondif, qui est un verbe conjugué (sans accord avec la personne, mais conjugué quand même), le participe présent n'est pas forcément un verbe, mais peut être un adjectif, comme dans la phrase "tu es embêtant". Cette distinction grammaticale explique peut être la redondance, tant pour le participe présent que pour le participe passé.

Comment: Le participe passé n'est pas systématiquement homophone au passé simple. *VOIR*, par exemple, a un radical **vi** au passé simple et **vy** au participe passé...

Comment: Je voulais dire le passé composé. C'est corrigé.

Comment: La phrase *tu es **fatigant*** n'est pas très bien choisie puisque c'est justement l'un des cas où l'adjectif n'est pas orthographié de la même façon que le participe présent correspondant : *fatig**u**ant*.

Comment: Merci, c'est vrai. Je viens de le corriger.

Comment: @GAM PUB: Pouvez-vous expliquer "vi" et "vy", svp ?

Comment: @HarryAudus c’est la notation phonétique pour vit et vu...

Comment: Bien sûr. Merci, GP.